# How do you display Greek symbols in mpld3 (Python Matplotlib D3) plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

The conventional plt.title(r'$\alpha$') for instance does not work in mpld3.enable_notebook(), whereas it does in normal matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: Are you specifying UTF-8 as your content-type in the resulting HTML page?  What does the final output SVG look like? Is the greek letter in there?  With SVG and the correct content-type you can just use unicode characters...

Comment: this runs the title through LaTeX, just to produce the α symbol. Why not use UTF-8 encoding and do: `plt.title(u'α')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many features of `mpl` that is not yet supported in `mpld3`.  It would be great to have, and some steps towards implementation [have been recorded here](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/14).  Patches most definitely welcome!